# how to convert a text to dict in order to iterate it in python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

What i am trying to do is to iterate. I have this line of code in one column in a table in my database:

```
[{u"item": 5, u"quantity": 2},{u"item": 6, u"quantity": 1}]
```

i assign this to a variable order so i have:

```
order = [{u"item": 5, u"quantity": 2},{u"item": 6, u"quantity": 1}]
```

then
i want to iterate it. I am trying the follow:

```
   for o in order.items():
        product = o['item']
        ...
```

it doesn't work. How can i convert it?

```
    for order in orders:
        ord = order.shopping_cart_details # [{u"item": 5, u"quantity": 2},{u"item": 6, u"quantity": 1}]
        temp = {'order_id': order.id, 'movies': ord['item'], 'created': order.created}
        full_results.append(temp)
```

i get string indices must be integers

Comment: You forgot to include the full error message. I can *guess* that it'd be `AttributeError` because a list object has no `.items()` method, but please make this *explicit*. *doesn't work* is not a problem description.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i edit my question..

Comment: Include the *full traceback* please. That contains a lot of information we now have to guess at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the order is a string

```
order = '[{"item": 5, "quantity": 2},{"item": 6, "quantity": 1}]'

def doSomething():
    import json
    ord = json.loads(order) 
    values =[ v['item'] for v in ord] # if u want a single item u put values = v.pop()['item']
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the return data type after you retrieve the data from database for the following code:

```
[{u"item": 5, u"quantity": 2},{u"item": 6, u"quantity": 1}]
```

Use `type(order)` to determine the type of the return value. It might be that the return data for the above data is in string format. In this case, when you store the list into database, you may consider to use `json.dumps()` to convert the data first then later when you retrieve the data, you may use `json.loads()` to get back the original data type. In this case, you may consider to change the database column type to `blob`.

Comment: I check it and you are correct. I store in database as a string. If i change it and do it in your way how i could iterate it later? I would like to get every item in the array. Thanks!

Comment: If you store the above information after json.dumps(), after you retrieve the information from database, you may just do a json.loads(). For example,  order = database.getdata() then order = json.loads(order), after this step you may use :  for every_item in order: item_id = every_item['item']  item_quantity = every_item['quantity']  . Please  kindly change the indentation and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Or to make it more simple you can use `eval` function.

```
order = '[{u"item": 5, u"quantity": 2},{u"item": 6, u"quantity": 1}]'
order = eval(order)
for o in order:
    product = o['item']
    print product
```